# File input "value" attribute failing html validation

Tags: php, html, validation, file-upload, yii2

I have done some looking around for a solution of this problem, but I seem to be at a dead end. Some articles say, that the `value` attribute for a file input field has to be omitted, where as other articles state the exact opposite. I am using https://validator.w3.org/nu/ to check my HTML for errors, and this is the last remaining one.

The website is build on top of the Yii2 framework, using [Kartik`s file upload widget](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput) with the following code:

```
echo FileInput::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'file',
    'options' => ['multiple' => false],
    'pluginOptions' => [
         'allowedFileExtensions'=>['doc', 'docx', 'jpg', 'png', 'pdf'],
         'showUpload' => false,
         'browseLabel' => '',
         'removeLabel' => '',
         'mainClass' => 'input-group-lg'
        ]
]);
```

The error I get when I try to validate my HTML code is the following:
`Attribute value not allowed on element input at this point.`, since apparently the widget puts a default `value=""` attribute in the file input field.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to solve this issue!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm amazed any article would be so bad as to claim that you *must* set an attribute which you can't set for security reasons.

Comment: usually a yii pattern is to hide when null or false so try    *'value' => false* or  *'value' => null*

Comment: @IvanButtinoni , I have already tried setting it to false but it did not work. I have also tried setting it to some random value, which also did not do the job.